# After creating the backup, verify that the file is not corrupted or was created with the correct data - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My application performs a backup via cmd, and I have no way of knowing if the backup is healthy. In some cases, the backup file is generated, but it is corrupted and I have already had a lot of headaches with it.

```
pg_dump.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --format tar --file c:\my_backup.backup my_database
```

During or after the backup process, is it possible to detect if there is a problem?
Thanks :)

Comment: A dump isn't really a backup to begin with: https://blog.dbi-services.com/what-is-a-database-backup-back-to-the-basics/

Comment: pg_dump doesn't randomly corrupt backups.  If it exited with a success code but it is actually corrupt, you should figure out what is going on rather than just wallpaper over it.  Which is not too say you shouldn't also test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PostgreSQL command that checks if a backup is readable and uncorrupted, unlike other RDBMS like Microsoft SQL Server's RESTORE VERIFYONLY command.

In fact a PostgreSQL backup file is not a backup but only a logical "dump" (series of SQL commands to reconstitute the database) unlike Oracle or SQL Server where the backup is a binary backup (data pages) which makes it possible to verify the internal checksum at the time of the backup or at any time after.

The only way to ensure that a PostgreSQL backup is consistent is to restore it ...! Of course, this approach is particularly poor in production ... (expensive in terms of time and volume!).

See the § "13 – Poor backup/restore strategies" in my paper : http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Comment: You might want to fix the spelling of PostgreSQL in your blog: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/the-shibboleth-of-postgresql/

Comment: Of course I do not. There is an explantion, a and this allows me to immediately and easily recognize my propse

Comment: If you refuse to write the product name correctly, how do you expect people reading your blog to take you seriously? Would you take a blog serious that constantly refers to "MicroSoft sql SerVER"?